# Codeigniter's redirect() and non-standard urls

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Codeigniter won't redirect the "url" `oauth://application` properly, pinning it after the current domain like so:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php/oauth://application
```

The code looks like this:

```
redirect("oauth://application", "location"); // changing to refresh doens't work either.
```

Any idea how to get this to work? I'm trying to redirect to an Android app.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might as well use PHP's native `header` function:

```
header('Location: oauth://application', TRUE, 302);
exit;
```

If you want to tweak CI's function, just create `application/helpers/my_url_helper.php` and adjust the `preg_match` URL check:

```
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
{
    // if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $uri))
    if ( ! preg_match('#^(https?|oauth)://#i', $uri))
    {
        $uri = site_url($uri);
    }

    switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
            break;
        default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
```